# Best way of searching HashSet

Tags: c#

I have a HashSet of Objs with Obj defined as such:

```
public class Obj 
{
    private int _id;
    private string _desc;
    private int _sum;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _desc; }
        set { _desc = value; }
    }

    public int Sum
    {
        get { return _sum; }
        set { _sum = value; }
    }

    public Obj(int id, string desc, int sum)
    {
        _id = id;
        _sum = sum;
        _desc = desc;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Obj other)
    {
        return this._sum == other._sum 
            && this._desc == other._desc;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + _sum.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + _desc.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

This works fine but I'm having trouble retrieving from the HashSet when `HashSet.Add(obj)` returns false.  What would be the best way to retrieve the `_id` of the `Obj` that is already contained in the `HashSet` in such a case?

Comment: Double `_`s? Mistake or not?

Comment: Any reason for the private variables. You could just do `public int ID {get;set;}`

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: @user2246674 `HashSet` has no `Get` method, or `TryGet` method, or anything like it; that's the root of the problem here.

Comment: @Servy Oh, doh. I was thinking of a Dictionary. In that case; simulate the HashSet?

Comment: There is subtle error in your code. HashCode and Equals should always be same for an object. In your case, you calculate both from Sum and Description, yet you are able to change both. This can cause errors if you add an Obj into a HashSet and then change either of those. Make them read-only to ensure no such error happens.

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks for the tip, I'm still fairly new to C#.

Comment: @Euphoric Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Or use a `Dictionary` instead?

Comment: @user1199931 You're fairly new to C# but it's still a very interesting question you ask here. I'm not sure it is possible with a complexity of _O(1)_ (expected complexity) with a `HashSet`.

Comment: @CédricBignon It's possible, if 1) it's converted to a dictionary and 2) there's no hash collisions.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Of course it is possible with another structure, however, it's interesting to know exactly what a structure can do, and what it can't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way i see it : sum + description (used for hashcode, equals) = key and _id (what you want to retrieve) = value.

The scenario clearly points to a dictionary rather than a hashset.... sets aren't meant for arbitrary lookup/retrieval.

Comment: But OP doesn’t really want a dictionary, they want to retrieve a *canonical element*. Sure, this can be phrased as a mapping. But set lookup would be much more straightforward. (But I agree that using a `Dictionary` is the best practical solution here).

Comment: I ended up going with Dictionary.  Doesn't make so much logical sense given my data setup but practically it makes sense as Konrad Rudolph says.

Answer (score 3):

```
myHashSet.First(x => x.Equals(myItemToRetrieve)).Id;
```

Another way to do this is to use a Dictionary (keys equal values):

(assuming you have converted it):

```
Obj temp;
if (theDictionary.TryGetValue(myItemToRetrieve, out temp))
{
    int ID = temp.Id;
}
else
{
    theDictionary[myItemToRetrieve] = myItemToRetrieve;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it's complexity for iteration (Used with `First`)

Comment: Note that the whole point of using a `HashSet` is to avoid doing linear searches.

Comment: @Servy With a proper hash set maybe. Not with `RetardedHashSet` which ships with .NET under the alias `HashSet`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph To be fair, this is an extraordinary odd request to have to begin with; generally there's no point in a `Get` method of a set, and there's the simple enough workaround of just using a `Dictionary<T, T>` instead that's not *too* cumbersome.  Removing methods that generally won't be used *can* be helpful.

Comment: @Servy I know, but the problem is that here it doesn't have any good methods for this.

Comment: @Servy It’s not odd at all, OP has just shown a legitimate use case. There’s a difference between “object identity” and “object identity for the purpose of a given lookup routine”. It’s occasionally convenient to treat the two separately, just like OP is doing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not saying it never makes sense, just that it *usually* doesn't.  Needing to do this is very rare.  I use HashSets constantly, and I've yet to be in a position in which I missed this method.  I'm not saying it's *wrong* to be in a position where you want to do this, it's just very unusual and uncommon, or to use another word "odd".

Comment: @Servy I get it. I still maintain that `HashSet` showcases incredibly poor API design here. I’m all for concise interfaces, but this doesn’t strike me as a *reasonable* restriction, especially since it’s not simply a missing shortcut, it’s making an operation *impossible* just by not exposing one public method (which already exists as a private operation), and which requires essentially replicating the *whole* class in order to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own collection type that builds on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and provides a `GetOrAdd` method (similar to the [`GetOrAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378674.aspx) of `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`):

```
public partial class HashDictionary<T> : Dictionary<T, T>
{
    public T GetOrAdd(T newItem)
    {
        T oldItem;
        if (this.TryGetValue(newItem, out oldItem))
            return oldItem;

        this.Add(newItem, newItem);
        return newItem;
    }
}
```

To use this, you would call:

```
Obj presentO = myHashDictionary.GetOrAdd(newO);
if (presentO == newO)
{
    // The item was not already present, and has been added.
}
else
{
    // A collision occurred, and presentO points to the existent item.
    int alreadyContainedID = presentO.ID;
}
```

In order to preserve compatibility with your current code, you could extend this class to implement `ICollection<T>` (or, preferably, `ISet<T>`) too:

```
public partial class HashDictionary<T> : ICollection<T>
{        
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.GetOrAdd(item);
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this.Keys.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had troubles with this situation in the past.  Granted, I was using a Dictionary<TKey,TValue>, which makes it easier to get the object based on a key.  When you override the hashcode, one problem is that Hashtables and such store the record according to the INITIAL values.  So if you fiddle with the object a bit, you will no longer be able to recover the object because the hash code has changed.  So the trick that I used was to have an integer hash code with a separate method like

```
private hashcode;

public void UpdateHashCode(){
   hashcode = // your original logic here.

}
```

That way, you can control when the hashcode gets updated, so that you can still find your old object. remove it from the dictionary, then update your object, then store the modified object.

But purists won't like that since it means strict equality testing and hash testing won't work correctly on modified objects that haven't had their hash updated.  So instead, you can just track the old hash code as a separate property that only gets updated when you are adding it to the dictionary.

```
private int oldHashcode;

public int OldHashcode{
   get{
       return oldHashCode;
   }
   set {
       oldHashCode = value;
   }
}
```

And when you add to the dictionary:

```
item.OldHashCode = item.GetHashCode();
```

And to retrieve

```
item = myDictionary[item.OldHashCode];
```

or whatever.

Comment: That isn’t really OP’s question although it’s true. In OP’s case, however, the `Id` simply doesn’t form part of the object identity. The rest remains unchanged, and so does the object’s hash value.

Comment: Ah, I assumed he already knew how to get an object back out of the HashSet in principle, but was having problems.